# Sort a 2D JavaScript array based on three columns which contain undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get three columns sorted in an array in Google Apps Script. I realize there are lots of explanations, but I'm not getting it. I was hoping someone could troubleshoot the code snipper below.

**Desired functionality:** sort an array using 'columns' 8,9,10 (text and nulls), in order.

**Issue:** nulls don't seem to get sorted properly.

Code snippet:

```
shdv.sort(function(a,b){
  var so = -1
a[10]>b[10] ? so=1 : null; // section
a[10] == b[10] && (a[9]>b[9] || a[9] == '') ? so=1 : null;
a[10] == b[10] && a[9]==b[9] && a[8]>a[9] ? so=1 : null;
null;
})
```

Example result

```
[Not Tracking, Site, 2.85208117E8]
[Not Tracking, , 2.83812926E8]
[Not Tracking, , 2.83991529E8]
[Not Tracking, Site, 2.83812602E8]
```

Desired result

```
[Not Tracking, Site, 2.85208117E8]
[Not Tracking, Site, 2.83812602E8]
[Not Tracking, , 2.83812926E8]
[Not Tracking, , 2.83991529E8]
```

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Your sort function has typos and  doesn't return anything. Also provide sample values for  `shdv`

Comment: Can't you use `range.sort([{column:8,ascending:true},{column:9,ascending:true},{column:10,ascending:true}])` [Example here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Comment: typo in code fixed...

Comment: @Cooper - thanks but this is for array only / no spreadsheet calls to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation:**

- You are trying to sort based on `undefined` values in the array.
- You can directly compare the elements like that: `a[1]==undefined`, `b[1]==undefined`;

**Code snippet:**

```js
  const shdv = [
    ["Not Tracking", "Site", 2.85208117E8],
    ["Not Tracking", , 2.83812926E8],
    ["Not Tracking", , 2.83991529E8],
    ["Not Tracking", "Site", 2.83812602E8]
    ];
  
  shdv.sort( (a,b) => 
            // if same sort equally
            a[1]==b[1]?0:
            //if nulls put them in the bottom
            a[1]==undefined?1: 
            b[1]==undefined?-1:
            //sort based on 1st and 3rd element
            a[0].charCodeAt(0)-b[0].charCodeAt(0) || a[2]<b[2]  );
  console.log(shdv);
```

The `console.log(shdv)` in `GAS` returns the expected result:

[image]

**References:**

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: is there any potential issue with just doing a[1]==undefined?1:  instead of ?1:null;
the full argument and line close seems necessary. does documentation say all that is optional?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can try it out if it works for you that way. However, I do prefer structured (complete) code so it is easy to be explained, maintained, understood. If less code works for you, then feel free to do it. But I don't think you will get more performance doing so in this scenario. @JasonTorpy Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

fix is to add at the end

```
return so;
```

so the sort actually sees the result.
But I'm interested in any suggestions about how to do this better (array only / no spreadsheet calls)